# Algorithm to get the excel-like column name of a number

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization

I'm working on a script that generate some Excel documents and I need to convert a number into its column name equivalent. For example:

```
1 => A
2 => B
27 => AA
28 => AB
14558 => UMX
```

I have already written an algorithm to do so, but I'd like to know whether are simpler or faster ways to do it:

```
function numberToColumnName($number){
    $abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $abc_len = strlen($abc);

    $result_len = 1; // how much characters the column's name will have
    $pow = 0;
    while( ( $pow += pow($abc_len, $result_len) ) < $number ){
        $result_len++;
    }

    $result = "";
    $next = false;
    // add each character to the result...
    for($i = 1; $i<=$result_len; $i++){
        $index = ($number % $abc_len) - 1; // calculate the module

        // sometimes the index should be decreased by 1
        if( $next || $next = false ){
            $index--;
        }

        // this is the point that will be calculated in the next iteration
        $number = floor($number / strlen($abc));

        // if the index is negative, convert it to positive
        if( $next = ($index < 0) ) {
            $index = $abc_len + $index;
        }

        $result = $abc[$index].$result; // concatenate the letter
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Do you know a better way to do it? Maybe something to keep it simpler? or a performance improvement?

#### Edit

ircmaxell's implementation works pretty fine. But, I'm going to add this nice short one:

```
function num2alpha($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: first comment in this man page might be helpful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#96304

Comment: Wow! That's a short implementation. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at any of the existing libraries to generate Excel documents from PHP?

Comment: Yes... of course. I'm using your awesome library, Mark. I just like to improve my skills at writing algorithms... what is nice about it is that after you have finished one, you can find other algorithms that does exactly the same but are shorter.

Comment: Your short algorithm uses 0 -> A rather than 1 -> A in your request, slightly different to the request... if that's what you want, look at PHPExcel's PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() method, although your num2alpha() implementation might be faster... I'll be running some tests, and may "borrow" it (with permission)

Comment: Results of timing tests: Call time for 1,048,576 iterations of PHPExcel's stringFromColumnIndex() method was 12.9545 seconds. Call time for 1,048,576 iterations of num2Alpha() method was 16.0076 seconds

Comment: Wow... then, I will use your implementation, Mark. Anyway, it was really funny trying to code that algorithm :D

Comment: Can't guarantee that result: running on a different server - Call time for 1,048,576 iterations of num2alpha() method was 5.6754 seconds; Call time for 1,048,576 iterations of PHPExcel's stringFromColumnIndex() method was 7.7286 seconds

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Here's a nice simple recursive function (Based on zero indexed numbers, meaning 0 == A, 1 == B, etc)...

```
function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

And if you want it one indexed (1 == A, etc):

```
function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $numeric = ($num - 1) % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval(($num - 1) / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return getNameFromNumber($num2) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

Tested with numbers from 0 to 10000...

Comment: I have translated this PHP script to JS: https://gist.github.com/terox/161db6259e8ddb56dd77

Comment: I doubt if recusive function is good or not if used in a loop? Could it cause stack space problem?

Comment: it helped me with createing a spreadsheet, where I needed to convert numeric index to letter index for spread sheet column names.

Answer (score 127):

Using **PhpSpreadsheet** (*PHPExcel is deprecated*)

```
// result = 'A'
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(1);
```

Note index 0 results in 'Z'

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

---

The correct answer (if you use **PHPExcel** Library) is:

```
// result = 'A'
$columnLetter = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(0); // ZERO-based!
```

and backwards:

```
// result = 1
$colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString('A');
```

Comment: stringFromColumnIndex(1) returns 'B'

Comment: `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(1)` indeed returns `'B'`, please edit your answer.

Comment: When using PhpSpreadSheet package, this answer is the best. Remember that PHPExcel is no longer maintained. so use PhpSpreadsheet package instead.

Answer (score 13):

Indexed for 1 -> A, 2 -> B, etc

```
function numToExcelAlpha($n) {
    $r = 'A';
    while ($n-- > 1) {
        $r++;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Indexed for 0 -> A, 1 -> B, etc

```
function numToExcelAlpha($n) {
    $r = 'A';
    while ($n-- >= 1) {
        $r++;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Takes advantage of the fact that PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented.

Comment: it's a good solution but I think it will time out the server on big numbers like 1234567789.

Answer (score 6):

This will do to conversion (assuming integer arithmetic), but I agree with the other posters; just use `base_convert`

```
function numberToColumnName($number)
{
    $abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $len = strlen($abc);

    $result = "";
    while ($number > 0) {
       $index  = $number % $len;
       $result = $abc[$index] . $result;
       $number = floor($number / $len);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This will return `B` for `$number = 1` instead of `A` since `1 % 26` is `1`

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but here's what I did (for 1==A indexed):

```
function num_to_letters($num, $uppercase = true) {
    $letters = '';
    while ($num > 0) {
        $code = ($num % 26 == 0) ? 26 : $num % 26;
        $letters .= chr($code + 64);
        $num = ($num - $code) / 26;
    }
    return ($uppercase) ? strtoupper(strrev($letters)) : strrev($letters);
}
```

Then if you want to convert the other way:

```
function letters_to_num($letters) {
    $num = 0;
    $arr = array_reverse(str_split($letters));

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $num += (ord(strtolower($arr[$i])) - 96) * (pow(26,$i));
    }
    return $num;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Number convert to Excel column letters:**

```
/**
 * Number convert to Excel column letters
 * 
 * 1 = A
 * 2 = B
 * 3 = C
 * 27 = AA
 * 1234567789 = CYWOQRM
 * 
 * @link https://vector.cool/php-number-convert-to-excel-column-letters-2
 * 
 * @param int  $num       欄數
 * @param bool $uppercase 大小寫
 * @return void
 */
function num_to_letters($n)
{
    $n -= 1;
    for ($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n % 26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}
```

ex:

```
echo num_to_letters(1);          // A
echo num_to_letters(2);          // B
echo num_to_letters(3);          // C
echo num_to_letters(27);         // AA
echo num_to_letters(1234567789); // CYWOQRM
```

**Excel column letters convert to Number:**

```
/**
 * Excel column letters convert to Number
 *
 * A = 1
 * B = 2
 * C = 3
 * AA = 27
 * CYWOQRM = 1234567789
 * 
 * @link https://vector.cool/php-number-convert-to-excel-column-letters-2
 * 
 * @param string $letters
 * @return mixed
 */
function letters_to_num($a)
{
    $l = strlen($a);
    $n = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++)
        $n = $n * 26 + ord($a[$i]) - 0x40;
    return $n;
}
```

ex:

```
echo letters_to_num('A');       // 1
echo letters_to_num('B');       // 2
echo letters_to_num('C');       // 3
echo letters_to_num('AA');      // 27
echo letters_to_num('CYWOQRM'); // 1234567789
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function numberToColumnName($number){
    $abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $abc_len = strlen($abc);

    $result = "";
    $tmp = $number;

    while($number > $abc_len) {
        $remainder = $number % $abc_len;
        $result = $abc[$remainder-1].$result;
        $number = floor($number / $abc_len);
    }
    return $abc[$number-1].$result;
}

echo numberToColumnName(1)."\n";
echo numberToColumnName(25)."\n";
echo numberToColumnName(26)."\n";
echo numberToColumnName(27)."\n";
echo numberToColumnName(28)."\n";
echo numberToColumnName(14558)."\n";
?>
```

Comment: Nice try! It will fail though... give it a try with 2049 and you will see :D

Answer (score 2):

Combining ircmaxell's recursive answer I've got this one:

```
    function getNameFromNumber($num, $index=0) {
        $index = abs($index*1); //make sure index is a positive integer
        $numeric = ($num - $index) % 26; 
        $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
        $num2 = intval(($num -$index) / 26);
        if ($num2 > 0) {
            return getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1 + $index) . $letter;
        } else {
            return $letter;
        }
    }
```

I'm using the default indexing as 0 based, but it can be any positive integer for when juggling with arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never use this in production because it's not readable, but for fun...
Only does up to ZZ.

```
<?php
    $col = 55;
    print (($n = (int)(($col - 1) / 26)) ? chr($n + 64) : '') . chr((($col - 1) % 26) + 65);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a *Javascript* implementation of this, here is [@ircmaxell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302991/7115122) in **Javascript**..

```js
function getNameFromNumber(num){
    let numeric = num%26;
    let letter = String.fromCharCode(65+numeric);
    let num2 = parseInt(num/26);
    if(num2 > 0) {
      return getNameFromNumber(num2 - 1)+letter;
    } else {
      return letter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another impl I just wrote:

```php
function excelColumnName($number) {
    $ordA = ord('A');
    $ordZ = ord('Z');
    $len = $ordZ - $ordA + 1;

    $result = '';
    while($number >= 0) {
        $result = chr($number % $len + $ordA) . $result;
        $number = intval($number/$len) - 1;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Some test inputs:

```php
>>> excelColumnName(0)
=> "A"
>>> excelColumnName(1)
=> "B"
>>> excelColumnName(25)
=> "Z"
>>> excelColumnName(26)
=> "AA"
>>> excelColumnName(27)
=> "AB"
>>> excelColumnName(28)
=> "AC"
>>> excelColumnName(52)
=> "BA"
>>> excelColumnName(51)
=> "AZ"
```