# How to create a function that converts a Number to a Bijective Hexavigesimal?

Tags: javascript, excel, hexavigesimal

Maybe i am just not that good enough in math, but I am having a problem in converting a number into pure alphabetical [Bijective Hexavigesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems#Bijective_numeration) just like how Microsoft Excel/OpenOffice Calc do it.

Here is a version of my code but did not give me the output i needed:

```
    var toHexvg = function(a){
     var x='';
     var let="_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     var len=let.length;
     var b=a;
     var cnt=0;
     var y = Array();
     do{
      a=(a-(a%len))/len;
      cnt++;
     }while(a!=0)
     a=b;
     var vnt=0;
     do{
      b+=Math.pow((len),vnt)*Math.floor(a/Math.pow((len),vnt+1));
      vnt++;
     }while(vnt!=cnt)
     var c=b;
     do{
      y.unshift( c%len );
      c=(c-(c%len))/len;
     }while(c!=0)
     for(var i in y)x+=let[y[i]];
     return x;
    }
```

The best output of my efforts can get is: `a b c d ... y z ba bb bc` - though not the actual code above.  The intended output is suppose to be `a b c ... y z aa ab ac ... zz aaa aab aac ... zzzzz aaaaaa aaaaab`, you get the picture.

Basically, my problem is more on doing the ''math'' rather than the function.  Ultimately my question is: How to do the Math in Hexavigesimal conversion, till a [supposed] infinity, just like Microsoft Excel.

And if possible, a source code, thank you in advance.

Comment: `aa` does not really make sense. It's `00`. The "number" after `z` is `ba`, so your output seems to be correct. Or is `_` your `0`, which seems kinda odd?

Comment: uhm, sorry about the sample code, guess i shouldn't posted it, I think it made expressing my question more complicated, ahaha... But, i guess my bottom line is that I need a code that outputs the y z aa ab and not y x ba bb... And you could say '_' is the 0, but the situation i need is that no part of the output may contain any '_'... ^^ hmmm

Comment: ^ [corrections]:  And you could say '\_' (underscore) is the 0, but the situation i need is that no part of the output may NOT contain any '\_' (underscore)...

Comment: @FelixKling - If you counted to infinity in base 27 with "_" = 0, "a" = 1, .. "z" = 26, "a_" = 27, "aa" = 28, etc., then you struck out all values containing "_" (0) in any "digit", the sequence remaining is how spreadsheet software labels columns. So determining what label goes with, say, column 589 is not just a conversion to base 26 or base 27...

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3302857/445425) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/297213/445425) addressing the same issue in other languages may give some clues

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes I understood now. I missed the *bijective* part, but Wikipedia was helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: Oh dear - base 27? What was I thinking? This is what happens when I post at midnight.

Comment: Thanks for asking this - I was trying to do the same thing and resorted to Googling it.

Comment: I wrote a function to do this and I had absolutely no idea what to name it. :-( I actually [had to ask on a different SE site](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/300389/), where the first answer brought me to this. +1 for teaching me the word "bijective numeration").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, here's my attempt, assuming you want the sequence to be start with "a" (representing 0) and going:

```
a, b, c, ..., y, z, aa, ab, ac, ..., zy, zz, aaa, aab, ...
```

This works and hopefully makes some sense. The funky line is there because it mathematically makes more sense for 0 to be represented by the empty string and then "a" would be 1, etc.

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function hex(a) {
  // First figure out how many digits there are.
  a += 1; // This line is funky
  c = 0;
  var x = 1;      
  while (a >= x) {
    c++;
    a -= x;
    x *= 26;
  }

  // Now you can do normal base conversion.
  var s = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    s = alpha.charAt(a % 26) + s;
    a = Math.floor(a/26);
  }

  return s;
}
```

However, if you're planning to simply print them out in order, there are far more efficient methods. For example, using recursion and/or prefixes and stuff.

Comment: Thank you!! ^^ You're awesome..! I never thought of doing it that way... Thank you much... I'll be putting ur name in the credits once the site is up and running, thank you... - ^^

Comment: No worries, no need for credit, code should be shared and manipulated freely. Besides, user826788 isn't very romantic... Thanks @Jesse, didn't even notice!

Comment: This would be the recursion method: 
`alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`
`function a(num) { num = num > 0? num - 1 : 0; if (num < alpha.length) return alpha[num]; else return a(Math.floor(num/alpha.length)) + '' + alpha[num%alpha.length];  }`

Answer (score 3):

Although @user826788 has already posted a working code (which is even a third quicker), I'll post my own work, that I did before finding the posts here (as i didnt know the word "hexavigesimal"). However it also includes the function for the other way round. Note that I use a = 1 as I use it to convert the starting list element from

```
aa) first
ab) second
```

to

```
<ol type="a" start="27">
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
</ol>
```

:

```
function linum2int(input) {
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/, '');
    output = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output = output * 26 + parseInt(input.substr(i, 1), 26 + 10) - 9;
    }
    console.log('linum', output);
    return output;
}

function int2linum(input) {

    var zeros = 0;
    var next = input;
    var generation = 0;
    while (next >= 27) {
        next = (next - 1) / 26 - (next - 1) % 26 / 26;
        zeros += next * Math.pow(27, generation);
        generation++;
    }
    output = (input + zeros).toString(27).replace(/./g, function ($0) {
        return '_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.charAt(parseInt($0, 27));
    });
    return output;
}

linum2int("aa"); // 27
int2linum(27); // "aa"
```

Comment: Btw in firefox the upper limit for `type="a"` lists is `2147483647` or `fxshrxw` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with recursion, like this:

```
const toBijective = n => (n > 26 ? toBijective(Math.floor((n - 1) / 26)) : "") + ((n % 26 || 26) + 9).toString(36);
// Parsing is not recursive
const parseBijective = str => str.split("").reverse().reduce((acc, x, i) => acc + ((parseInt(x, 36) - 9) * (26 ** i)), 0);

toBijective(1) // "a"
toBijective(27) // "aa"
toBijective(703) // "aaa"
toBijective(18279) // "aaaa"
toBijective(127341046141) // "overflow"

parseBijective("Overflow") // 127341046141
```

Comment: this isn't bijective, as 0 should map to A, not B

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how to work it out from a formula, but I fooled around with it for a while and came up with the following algorithm to literally count up to the requested column number:

```
var getAlpha = (function() {
    var alphas = [null, "a"],
        highest = [1];

    return function(decNum) {
        if (alphas[decNum])
            return alphas[decNum];

        var d,
            next,
            carry,
            i = alphas.length;

        for(; i <= decNum; i++) {
            next = "";
            carry = true;
            for(d = 0; d < highest.length; d++){
                if (carry) {
                    if (highest[d] === 26) {
                        highest[d] = 1;
                    } else { 
                        highest[d]++;
                        carry = false;
                    }
                }
                next = String.fromCharCode(
                          highest[d] + 96)
                     + next;
            }
            if (carry) {
                highest.push(1);
                next = "a" + next;
            }
            alphas[i] = next;
        }

        return alphas[decNum];
    };
})();


alert(getAlpha(27));     // "aa"
alert(getAlpha(100000)); // "eqxd"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6SE2f/1/

The `highest` array holds the current highest number with an array element per "digit" (element 0 is the least significant "digit").

When I started the above it seemed a good idea to cache each value once calculated, to save time if the same value was requested again, but in practice (with Chrome) it only took about 3 seconds to calculate the 1,000,000th value (`bdwgn`) and about 20 seconds to calculate the 10,000,000th value (`uvxxk`). With the caching removed it took about 14 seconds to the 10,000,000th value.

Answer (score 0):

Just finished writing [this code](https://github.com/Alhadis/Snippets/commit/30cd58e0789493b0a79b34258dcf715a606a56c0) earlier tonight, and I found this question while on a quest to figure out what to name the damn thing. Here it is (in case anybody feels like using it):

```
/**
 * Convert an integer to bijective hexavigesimal notation (alphabetic base-26).
 *
 * @param {Number} int - A positive integer above zero
 * @return {String} The number's value expressed in uppercased bijective base-26
 */
function bijectiveBase26(int){
    const sequence    = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const length      = sequence.length;

    if(int <= 0)      return int;
    if(int <= length) return sequence[int - 1];


    let index  = (int % length) || length;
    let result = [sequence[index - 1]];

    while((int = Math.floor((int - 1) / length)) > 0){
        index = (int % length) || length;
        result.push(sequence[index - 1]);
    }

    return result.reverse().join("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this same problem today for work. My solution is written in Elixir and uses recursion, but I explain the thinking in plain English.

Here are some example transformations:

0 -> "A", 1 -> "B", 2 -> "C", 3 -> "D", ..
25 -> "Z", 26 -> "AA", 27 -> "AB", ...

At first glance it might seem like a normal 26-base counting system
but unfortunately it is not so simple.
The "problem" becomes clear when you realize:

```
A = 0
AA = 26
```

This is at odds with a normal counting system, where "0" does not behave
as "1" when it is in a decimal place other than then unit.

To understand the algorithm, consider a simpler but equivalent base-2 system:

```
A = 0
B = 1
AA = 2
AB = 3
BA = 4
BB = 5
AAA = 6
```

In a normal binary counting system we can determine the "value" of decimal places by
taking increasing powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) and the value of a binary number is
calculated by multiplying each digit by that digit place's value.
e.g. 10101 = 1 * (2 ^ 4) + 0 * (2 ^ 3) + 1 * (2 ^ 2) + 0 * (2 ^ 1) + 1 * (2 ^ 0) = 21

In our more complicated AB system, we can see by inspection that the decimal place values are:

```
1, 2, 6, 14, 30, 62
```

The pattern reveals itself to be `(previous_unit_place_value + 1) * 2`.
As such, to get the next lower unit place value, we divide by 2 and subtract 1.

This can be extended to a base-26 system. Simply divide by 26 and subtract 1.

Now a formula for transforming a normal base-10 number to special base-26 is apparent.
Say the input is `x`.

1. Create an accumulator list `l`.
2. If x is less than 26, set `l = [x | l]` and go to step 5. Otherwise, continue.
3. Divide x by 2. The floored result is `d` and the remainder is `r`.
4. Push the remainder as head on an accumulator list. i.e. `l = [r | l]`
5. Go to step 2 with with (d - 1) as input, e.g. `x = d - 1`
6. Convert  """ all elements of `l` to their corresponding chars. 0 -> A, etc.

So, finally, here is my answer, written in Elixir:

```
defmodule BijectiveHexavigesimal do
  def to_az_string(number, base \\ 26) do
    number
    |> to_list(base)
    |> Enum.map(&to_char/1)
    |> to_string()
  end

  def to_09_integer(string, base \\ 26) do
    string
    |> String.to_charlist()
    |> Enum.reverse()
    |> Enum.reduce({0, nil}, fn
      char, {_total, nil} ->
        {to_integer(char), 1}

      char, {total, previous_place_value} ->
        char_value = to_integer(char + 1)
        place_value = previous_place_value * base
        new_total = total + char_value * place_value
        {new_total, place_value}
    end)
    |> elem(0)
  end

  def to_list(number, base, acc \\ []) do
    if number < base do
      [number | acc]
    else
      to_list(div(number, base) - 1, base, [rem(number, base) | acc])
    end
  end

  defp to_char(x), do: x + 65
end
```

You use it simply as `BijectiveHexavigesimal.to_az_string(420)`. It also accepts on optional "base" arg.

I know the OP asked about Javascript but I wanted to provide an Elixir solution for posterity.

Comment: you have a fundamental misunderstanding of bijective bases. you start counting at 1, there is no value for 0. to steal your table:
```
; ; ; ; ; ; A = 1*2^0 = 1 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
B = 2*2^0 = 2 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
AA = 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 3 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
AB = 1*2^1 + 2*2^0 = 4 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
BA = 2*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 5 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
BB = 2*2^1 + 2*2^0 =  6 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
AAA = 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 7 ; ; ; ; ; ;
```
they work the same as normal bases, they just represent the base number with one digit instead of using 10 to represent the base number.

Comment: @guest4308 You are right. When I wrote this, I did not understand that bijective bases have no zero.

Answer (score 0):

I have published these functions in npm package here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gkucmierz/utils

Converting bijective numeration to number both ways (also BigInt version is included).

https://github.com/gkucmierz/utils/blob/main/src/bijective-numeration.mjs