# Add alphabets dynamically as html row increments

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to ensure i have a dynamic increment of Alphabets in a new cell on left side, next to each cell in a row which is dynamically created based on the option chosen in Select. This newly generated alphabet will be considered as bullet points/serial number for that particular row's text box.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ksyy7L/2/)**

**js code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var select = $("#Number_of_position"), table = $("#Positions_names"); 
 for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        select.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }

    select.change(function () {
        var rows = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
            rows += "<tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>";
        }
        table.html(rows);
    });

});
```

**html**

```
<select id="Number_of_position">              
    </select>   <table id="Positions_names">
    </table>
```

Comment: what do you mean when you are talking about "Alphabets"? do you mean that you want to have the letters from a to z on the left side of your text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a base26 question, you can search for an implementation of this in javascript pretty easily - [How to create a function that converts a Number to a Bijective Hexavigesimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603480/how-to-create-a-function-that-converts-a-number-to-a-bijective-hexavigesimal)

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function hex(a) {
  // First figure out how many digits there are.
  a += 1; // This line is funky
  var c = 0;
  var x = 1;      
  while (a >= x) {
    c++;
    a -= x;
    x *= 26;
  }

  // Now you can do normal base conversion.
  var s = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    s = alpha.charAt(a % 26) + s;
    a = Math.floor(a/26);
  }

  return s;
}
```

So you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var select = $("#Number_of_position"), table = $("#Positions_names"); 
 for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        select.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }

    select.change(function () {
        var rows = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
            rows += "<tr><td>" + hex(i) + "</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>";
        }
        table.html(rows);
    });

});
```

Heres the example http://jsfiddle.net/v2ksyy7L/6/

And if you want it to be uppercase just do

```
hex(i).toUpperCase();
```

Also - this will work up to any number of rows that javascript can handle

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood you correctly, that's maybe what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/v2ksyy7L/3/

I have added an array for the alphabet:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

and then added the output to your "render" loop:

```
 rows += "<tr><td>" + alphabet[i] + " <input type='text'></td></tr>";
```

Comment: if i select more then 26 as there are no letters to display it displays undefined is there a way to create aa , ab, ac to as a auto increment as there are 100 select values can be selected