# Create File with Chart, and dynamic number of columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am creating an xlsx-file, and I want to add a column chart, displaying 2 values for a calenderweek.

However, I don't know how many charts (depending on the items available) and how many calenderweeks I'll have to display (depending on the time-frame selected by the user).

Creating the weeks and the data-table is not that problem, that is working fine,  iterating through my data with two nested foreach-loops, using setCellValueByColumnAndRow().

My problem is, I have a dynamic number of columns and a dynamic number of rows.
So I need a hint, how to transfer

```
$value = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 
   'Worksheet!$C$9:$H$9', 
   NULL, 
   $numberOfWeeks);

array_push($values, $value);
```

into something like this:

```
$value = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 
'Worksheet!$' . $START_COLUMN . '$' . $CURRENT_ROW . ':$' . $END_COLUMN . '$' . $CURRENT_ROW,
NULL,
$numberOfWeeks); 

array_push($values, $value);
```

How do I create the with a chart and a dynamic number of columns?

**EDIT:**

Within the snippet, there was a missing "!" (Thanks to Mark Barker). Fixed this in my first post. 
Because I was using Integer-Values to iterate through the colums, I had to convert the integer back to a letter. [A solution for this is posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302857/algorithm-to-get-the-excel-like-column-name-of-a-number).
In the meantime, Mark poked my nose to the function, build in of course ;-) ,
 `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()`

Answer (score 0):

Missing `!` after `Worksheet` is the obvious problem.... MS Excel cares about such things.... and missing `$` for the absolute references:

```
$value = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number',
    'Worksheet!$' . $START_COLUMN . '$' . $CURRENT_ROW . ':$' . $END_COLUMN . '$' . $CURRENT_ROW,
    NULL,
    $numberOfWeeks);
```

But this is really a simple matter of PHP string concatenation 101

Comment: Thank you! there was indeed something missing, but the main problem was, that i have the numeric represenation of the column, not the alpabetical value.

Answer (score 0):

While i am writing this answer the **PHPExcel is dead already** use **PhpSpreadsheet** instead.

Use `Coordinate` class method `stringFromColumnIndex()` which will return String of Excel Column from getting integer index number, (you can also use array's count if you have array).

```
$column = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(2);
// $column = 'B'
```

Here **it will count from 1** so **1 = 'A', 2 = 'B', 3 = 'C', etc.**

Be cautious; **Dont use 0, it will results in 'Z'**.

Reference: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to change the data range of an existing chart?  My chart is in a template with two rows, headings `=RawData!$A$1:$H$1` and data `=RawData$A$2 : $H$2`.  The chart exists on Sheet `ChartData`.  As I read in data to `RawData`, the data could expand (or shrink) out to column Q or Z (or ???), so accordingly I need recast the chart to match the new size of the data set.  Example: headings `=RawData!$A$1:$Q$1` and data `=RawData!$A$2 : $Q$2`.  But I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It is quite not easy to understand it fully you can ask it as new question stackoverflow community will definitely help you, but as I understood you want to do it dynamically then do it like get the length of data using `data.length` in php and then convert it to cell variable using `stringFromColumnIndex` and then you will get the dynamic cell name.

Comment: Hey, I clarified question yesterday with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179026/phpspreadsheet-how-to-change-the-data-set-assigned-to-a-chart-in-a-template-file