# How to generate rows and column key like Excel sheet using loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create loop that gives me this type of result just like excel rows and column.

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1 J1 K1 L1 M1 N1 O1 P1 Q1 R1 S1 T1 U1 V1 W1 X1 Y1 
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 I2 J2 K2 L2 M2 N2 O2 P2 Q2 R2 S2 T2 U2 V2 W2 X2 Y2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3 I3 J3 K3 L3 M3 N3 O3 P3 Q3 R3 S3 T3 U3 V3 W3 X3 Y3
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4 I4 J4 K4 L4 M4 N4 O4 P4 Q4 R4 S4 T4 U4 V4 W4 X4 Y4
```

I have create basic loop but I am confused to create loop.

```
<?php
    for ($char = 'A'; $char <= 'Y'; $char++) {

        echo $char.'2 ';

    }   
?>
```

I am not good with complex loop so I thankful If you guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to get the excel-like column name of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302857/algorithm-to-get-the-excel-like-column-name-of-a-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use another loop for that row:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) { // loop for rows
    for($letter = 'A'; $letter != 'Z'; $letter++) { // loop for columns
        echo $letter.$i . ' ';
    }
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

Or tabular:

```
<table border="1">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php for($letter = 'A'; $letter != 'Z'; $letter++): ?>
            <td><?php echo $letter.$i; ?></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for you great support :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a string with characters and loop through that string.

```
<?php
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($chars); $i++)
    {
        echo $chars[$i] . '2 ';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z'); // Generates an array of letters from A-Z
foreach ($n=1; $n<= 10; $n++) { // Loop through numbers from 1-10
    foreach ($letters as $l) { // Loop through the letters
        echo $l.$i; // Print out Letter and number e.g. A1, B1, C1...
    }
    echo "<br>"; // New line after a row of letters
}
```