# PhpSpreadsheet: Getting 'Invalid cell coordinate' error despite using integer column indices in setCellValueByColumnAndRow

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm encountering an issue with PhpSpreadsheet where I'm getting an "Invalid cell coordinate" error while trying to export an excel report from laravel project,

Specifically with coordinates like '01'. I've checked my code and ensured that I'm using integer column indices in setCellValueByColumnAndRow:

Here is the full code of my Controller method:

```
    public function getFestivalPlanRegister($id, $author = null)
        {
            if (request()->has('excel_export')){
                $festival = $festival->where('festival_plan.fsp_condition_plan', '=', 'completed');
            }
            
            if (request()->has('excel_export')) {
                $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
                $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setRightToLeft(true);
                $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    
                $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
                $active_sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
                $active_sheet->setRightToLeft(true);
    
                $style = [
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER],
                ];
    
                // Define the header row and style
                $headerColumns = [
                   'Registration ID', 'Project Tracking Code', 'Farsi Title of the Project', 
                   'English Title of the Project', 'Section',
                   'Axis', 'Challenge', 'Lead Author Name', 'Research Location', 'Lead Author 
                    Contact Number',
                    'Lead Author Email', 'Lead Author Address', 'Lead Author Postal Code', 'Lead 
                     Author Province',
                     'Lead Author City', 'Lead Author Academic Level', 'Lead Author Educational 
                     Level',
                     'Project Status', 'Collaborator Name', 'Collaborator National ID', 
                     'Collaborator Academic Level',
                     'Collaborator Educational Level', 'Collaborator Province', 'Collaborator 
                      City', 'Collaborator Educational Institution',
                     'Supervisor Name', 'Supervisor Contact Number', 'Supervisor Email', 
                     'Supervisor National ID',
                     'Supervisor Address', 'Supervisor Postal Code', 'Supervisor Academic Level', 
                     'Supervisor Field of Study',
                     'Supervisor Province', 'Supervisor City', 'First Stage Average Score', 
                     'Second Stage Average Score',
                     'Third Stage Average Score', 'Status'
                ];
    
                $style = [
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER],
                ];
    
                $row = 1;
                // Apply header row
                foreach ($headerColumns as $column => $header) {
                    $activeSheet->setCellValue("{$column}{$row}", $header);
                    $activeSheet->getStyle("{$column}{$row}")->applyFromArray($style);
                }
    
                $row = 2;
    
                foreach ($festival as $item) {
                    $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $item->fsp_code);
                    $activeSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->applyFromArray($style);
    
                    $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $row, $item->fsp_id);
                    $activeSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->applyFromArray($style);

                    ...
                    
                    $row++;
                }
                
                $filename = 'festival_report.xlsx';
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename\"");
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    
                $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
                $writer->save('php://output');
                die();
            }
            return $festival;
        }
```

And this is the error I get:

### **Invalid cell coordinate 01**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

So help me with this problem please... I'm really stuck at this point!

---

I still struggling with this error, I wrote the Spreadsheet.php class methods here:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setRightToLeft(true);

$activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            
public function getActiveSheet()
    {
        return $this->getSheet($this->activeSheetIndex);
    }

public function getSheet($pIndex)
    {
        if (!isset($this->workSheetCollection[$pIndex])) {
            $numSheets = $this->getSheetCount();

            throw new Exception(
                "Your requested sheet index: {$pIndex} is out of bounds. The actual number of sheets is {$numSheets}."
            );
        }

        return $this->workSheetCollection[$pIndex];
    }
    
public function getSheetCount()
    {
        return count($this->workSheetCollection);
    }
```

Comment: Could the 0 before the number be the problem?

Comment: I think the issue is with $column being an an integer from the array index, but setCellValue expects a letter-based column index. To fix this, convert $column to an Excel column letter and see if it works

Comment: FYI, if you have a value `01`, then that is most certainly _not_ an integer. Real numbers do not _have_ leading zeroes, ever.

Comment: @CBroe Right, so how to fix this, I've updated the question...

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Would you checked the question once again, and help me with this...

Comment: I don't see how those `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` could cause that error, first parameter is hard-coded as an integer, and `$row` looks like it could hardly be anything else either. I'm guessing the error actually comes from `$activeSheet->setCellValue("{$column}{$row}"` - you are looping over an array with a zero-based index there, so on the first iteration, `$column` _would_ be 0. But the column index isn't a number, it needs to be `A`, `B` etc. to begin with.

Comment: Replace `"{$column}{$row}"` with `chr(65 + $column) . $row` in both places (without `"` around it), and see what that gets you.

Comment: @CBroe Invalid cell coordinate [1 ` $activeSheet->setCellValue(chr(65 + $column) . $row, $header);`

Comment: @CBroe There are more than 26 columns here, so `chr(65 + $column)` will overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate after bounty period is over: [Algorithm to get the excel-like column name of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3302857/2943403)

Answer (score 3):

`setCellValue()` expects the cell coordinates in the form `'A1'`. That's not what you are doing here:

```
foreach ($headerColumns as $column => $header) {
    $activeSheet->setCellValue("{$column}{$row}", $header);
    $activeSheet->getStyle("{$column}{$row}")->applyFromArray($style);
}
```

`$column` is an integer, not a letter.

To fix this, one way is to use `getCellByColumnAndRow()`:

```
foreach ($headerColumns as $column => $header) {
    $cell = $activeSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column + 1, $row);
    $cell->setValue($header);
    $cell->getStyle()->applyFromArray($style);
}
```

Alternatively you can call `getCell()` with an array:

```
foreach ($headerColumns as $column => $header) {
    $cell = $activeSheet->getCell([$column + 1, $row]);
    $cell->setValue($header);
    $cell->getStyle()->applyFromArray($style);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in your `foreach` loop, I used the `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex()`  method to convert the numeric column index to its corresponding Excel column letter, try this

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

public function getFestivalPlanRegister($id, $author = null) {
    if (request()->has('excel_export')) {
        $festival = $festival->where('festival_plan.fsp_condition_plan', '=', 'completed');
    }

    if (request()->has('excel_export')) {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setRightToLeft(true);
        $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $style = [
            'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER],
        ];

        // Define the header row and style
        // ... your $headerColumns and $style declarations ...
    
        $row = 1;
        // Apply header row
        foreach ($headerColumns as $columnIndex => $header) {
            $columnLetter = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex + 1);
            $activeSheet->setCellValue("{$columnLetter}{$row}", $header);
            $activeSheet->getStyle("{$columnLetter}{$row}")->applyFromArray($style);
        }

        $row = 2;

        foreach ($festival as $item) {
            $columnLetter = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(1);
            $activeSheet->setCellValue("{$columnLetter}{$row}", $item->fsp_code);
            $activeSheet->getStyle("{$columnLetter}{$row}")->applyFromArray($style);

            // ... 

            $row++;
        }

        $filename = 'festival_report.xlsx';
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename\"");
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }

    return $festival;
}
```